# Update a Table with data from two other Tables using SQL and multiple criteria in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to develop a table where the available amount of multiple resources of given Workstations are shown. For this I use three tables. One where the entries are saved:

Table_Entry:

| Resource | Entry (kg) | WS1 | WS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coal | 100 | X |  |
| Iron | 300 | X |  |
| Iron | 500 |  | X |
| Iron | 100 | X |  |

Where Resource is a string, Entry(kg) a Double, WS1 and WS2 are Booleans.
Another one where the used resources are keept in record:

Table_Out:

| Resource | Out (kg) | WS1 | WS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coal | 50 | X |  |
| Iron | 200 | X |  |
| Iron | 300 |  | X |
| Iron | 100 | X |  |

And a last table to keep totals:

Table_Total:

| Resource | WS1 IN | WS1 OUT | WS2 IN | WS2 OUT | WS1 | WS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coal | 100 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 |
| Iron | 400 | 300 | 500 | 300 | 100 | 200 |

The user can add new entries to the table Table_Entry and Table_Out but can not directly interact with Table_Total. My approach to this is to make two update querys and append them to the save buttons on the first two table's data entry Forms and make WS1 as well as WS2 from the third table calculated fields. This is my SQL query for the Table_Entry so far:

```
UPDATE Table_Total SET Table_Total.[WS1 IN] = SELECT SUM ([Table_Entry].[Entry (kg)])
FROM [Table_Entry] 
WHERE [Table_Entry].[Resource] = [Table_Total].[Resource] AND [Table_Entry].WS1=True AND [Table_Entry].WS2=False

UPDATE Table_Total SET Table_Total.[WS2 IN] = SELECT SUM ([Table_Entry].[Entry (kg)]) 
FROM [Table_Entry] 
WHERE [Table_Entry].[Resource] = [Table_Total].[Resource] AND [Table_Entry].WS2=True AND [Table_Entry].WS1=False
```

I plan to do the same for Table_Out. My SQL code gives this error:

> Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT SUM([Table_Entry].[Entry (kg)])
> FROM [Table_Entry]'.

Can I formulate two UPDATE codes on a single SQL View page from an Update query like I intend to in Access? What is wrong with my code for it to show the error?

Comment: Thanks for pointing those notation mistakes out. Allready fixed them but keep having the  same error. Something else must be wrong. And you are totally right! Will probably use DSum() for my program, but still want to know how to solve this the SQL way to learn for future problems. Is there perhaps a JOIN error?

Comment: Ideally, don't keep a Totals table - calculate balances from raw transaction data when needed. Aggregate queries cannot be used as source for an UPDATE action. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html. And NO, multiple independent SQL statements cannot be in one query in SQLView. Definitely cannot have multiple action SQL.

Comment: Thanks @June7, you are allways eager to help. I am new to creating DataBases and will stick to the advice of not keeping totals in tables. Very usefull link. This question is solved.